# Backbone.Syphon - what is the proper way to validate a form?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, backbone.js, marionette

I have a form in my `view.js` - once the user click the submit, I am getting the form serialized and receiving the serialized data too..

but still i am not familiar with this new 'Syphon' - I am not much clear for validate the form. any one show me the right direction to validate the serialized data please...

here is my try and what i expect:

```
define([
    'jQuery','underscore',
    'backbone','marionette',
    'text!./templates/loginView.html'],
    function($,_,Backbone,Marionette,template){
        "use strict";

        var LoginView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

            className:'col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4',

            template:_.template(template),

            events:{
                "submit form" : "loginSubmit"
            },

            loginSubmit:function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(e.target); // i am getting serialized data properly.

                _.each(data, function(val,key){
                    if(!val) {
                        $el.select(); // i am looking some thing like this... hot to achieve?
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        return LoginView;
    }
);
```

May be the way I am doing could be wrong. please suggest me right way or correct me..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.Syphon aims to make it easy to serialize the form inputs of a Backbone.View in to a simple JSON object.

For validating the attributes, use the library [backbone.validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) and [StickIt(data binding in the model entity)](https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.stickit), the two libraries , work very well.

If you choose this option, **you will no longer need the library backbone.syphon**, the **stickyt**  already has the responsability of **set the attributes in the model entity**.

And when you make the submit of the form, the library **backbone.validation** will **check** your model entity attributes to **validate**.